# Parsing of Stackoverflow`s posts.xml on hadoop

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I am following this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620717/Building-A-Recommendation-Engine-Machine-Learning) by Anoop Madhusudanan on codeproject to build a recommendation engine not on cluster but on my system.

Problem is when i try to parse posts.xml whose structure is as follows:

```
 <row Id="99" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="88" CreationDate="2008-08-01T14:55:08.477" Score="2" Body="&lt;blockquote&gt;&#xD;&#xA;  &lt;p&gt;The actual resolution of gettimeofday() depends on the hardware architecture. Intel processors as well as SPARC machines offer high resolution timers that measure microseconds. Other hardware architectures fall back to the system’s timer, which is typically set to 100 Hz. In such cases, the time resolution will be less accurate. &lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;/blockquote&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I obtained this answer from &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&amp;amp;seqNum=272&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;High Resolution Time Measurement and Timers, Part I&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;" OwnerUserId="25" LastActivityDate="2008-08-01T14:55:08.477" />
```

Now I need to parse this file(size 1.4 gb) on hadoop for which i have written code in java and created its jar.
Java class is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.io.File;


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;


public class Recommend {

    static class Map extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        Path path;
        String fXmlFile;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory;
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        Document doc;

        /**
         * Given an output filename, write a bunch of random records to it.
         */
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            try{
                fXmlFile=value.toString();
                dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                dBuilder= dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc= dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");

                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    Text keyWords =new Text(eElement.getAttribute("OwnerUserId"));
                    Text valueWords = new Text(eElement.getAttribute("ParentId"));
                    String val=keyWords.toString()+" "+valueWords.toString();
                    // Write the sentence 
                    if(keyWords != null && valueWords != null){
                        output.collect(keyWords, new Text(val));
                    }
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        /*if (args.length != 2) {
          System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
          System.exit(2);
        }*/
//      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Recommend");
        job.setJarByClass(Recommend.class);
        
        // the keys are words (strings)
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        
        // the values are counts (ints)
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        //conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
       
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
         Path outPath = new Path(args[1]);
            FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(outPath.toUri(), conf);
            if (dfs.exists(outPath)) {
            dfs.delete(outPath, true);
            }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be as a file in hadoop containing output as `OwnerUserId ParentId`
but instead I get output as:

```
1599788   <row Id="2292" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="2284" CreationDate="2008-08-05T13:28:06.700" Score="0" ViewCount="0" Body="&lt;p&gt;The first thing you should do is contact the main people who run the open source project. Ask them if it is ok to contribute to the code and go from there.&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Simply writing your improved code and then giving it to them may result in your code being rejected.&lt;/p&gt;" OwnerUserId="383" LastActivityDate="2008-08-05T13:28:06.700" />
```

I dont know about the origin of `1599788` appearing as a key value from mapper.

I don`t know much about writing mapper classes for hadoop, I need help to modify my code to get the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and experiments , finally learnt the way to write map for parsin xml files which have syntax like one I provided. I changed my approach and this is my new mapper code... Its workin for my usecase.

hope it help someone and they can save their time :)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
    NullWritable obj;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer tok= new StringTokenizer(value.toString()); 
        String pa=null,ow=null,pi=null,v;
        while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String[] arr;
            String val = (String) tok.nextToken();
            if(val.contains("PostTypeId")){
                arr= val.split("[\"]");
                pi=arr[arr.length-1];
                if(pi.equals("2")){
                    continue;
                }
                else break;
            }
            if(val.contains("ParentId")){
                arr= val.split("[\"]");
                pa=arr[arr.length-1];
            } 
            else if(val.contains("OwnerUserId") ){
                arr= val.split("[\"]");
                ow=arr[arr.length-1];
                try {
                    if(pa!=null && ow != null){
                        v=String.format("{0},{1}", ow,pa);
                        context.write(obj,new Text(v));

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mapper I've written to parse the so posts xml and create a tab separated file(s) on hadoop to be used by other map reduce jobs or Hive or Pig.

Mapper

```
package com.aravind.learning.hadoop.mapred.techtalks;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

public class StackoverflowDataWranglerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
{
    static enum BadRecordCounters
    {
        NO_CREATION_DATE, UNKNOWN_USER_ID, UNPARSEABLE_RECORD, UNTAGGED_POSTS
    }

    private final Text outputKey = new Text();
    private final Text outputValue = new Text();

    private final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    private DocumentBuilder builder;
    private static final Joiner TAG_JOINER = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls();
    // 2008-07-31T21:42:52.667
    private static final DateFormat DATE_PARSER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_BUILDER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        try
        {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
            new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable inputKey, Text inputValue, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        try
        {
            String entry = inputValue.toString();
            if (entry.contains("<row "))
            {
                Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(entry)));
                Element rootElem = doc.getDocumentElement();

                String id = rootElem.getAttribute("Id");
                String postedBy = rootElem.getAttribute("OwnerUserId").trim();
                String viewCount = rootElem.getAttribute("ViewCount");
                String postTypeId = rootElem.getAttribute("PostTypeId");
                String score = rootElem.getAttribute("Score");
                String title = rootElem.getAttribute("Title");
                String tags = rootElem.getAttribute("Tags");
                String answerCount = rootElem.getAttribute("AnswerCount");
                String commentCount = rootElem.getAttribute("CommentCount");
                String favoriteCount = rootElem.getAttribute("FavoriteCount");
                String creationDate = rootElem.getAttribute("CreationDate");

                Date parsedDate = null;
                if (creationDate != null && creationDate.trim().length() > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        parsedDate = DATE_PARSER.parse(creationDate);
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e)
                    {
                        context.getCounter("Bad Record Counters", "Posts missing CreationDate").increment(1);
                    }
                }

                if (postedBy.length() == 0 || postedBy.trim().equals("-1"))
                {
                    context.getCounter("Bad Record Counters", "Posts with either empty UserId or UserId contains '-1'")
                            .increment(1);
                    try
                    {
                        parsedDate = DATE_BUILDER.parse("2100-00-01");
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e)
                    {
                        // ignore
                    }
                }

                tags = tags.trim();
                String tagTokens[] = null;

                if (tags.length() > 1)
                {
                    tagTokens = tags.substring(1, tags.length() - 1).split("><");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.getCounter("Bad Record Counters", "Untagged Posts").increment(1);
                }

                outputKey.clear();
                outputKey.set(id);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(postedBy).append("\t").append(parsedDate.getTime()).append("\t")
                        .append(postTypeId).append("\t").append(title).append("\t").append(viewCount).append("\t").append(score)
                        .append("\t");

                if (tagTokens != null)
                {
                    sb.append(TAG_JOINER.join(tagTokens)).append("\t");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.append("").append("\t");
                }
                sb.append(answerCount).append("\t").append(commentCount).append("\t").append(favoriteCount).toString();

                outputValue.set(sb.toString());

                context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
            }
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            context.getCounter("Bad Record Counters", "Unparsable records").increment(1);
        }
        finally
        {
            builder.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

**Driver**

```
public class StackoverflowDataWranglerDriver extends Configured implements Tool
{
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length != 2)
        {
            System.err.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <input> <output>\n", getClass().getSimpleName());
            ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
            return -1;
        }

        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());

        job.setJobName("Tech Talks - Stackoverflow Forum Posts - Data Wrangler");

        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setJarByClass(StackoverflowDataWranglerMapper.class);// required for mr1
        job.setMapperClass(StackoverflowDataWranglerMapper.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new StackoverflowDataWranglerDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

**Job submit command**

```
hadoop jar ./hadoop-examples-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.aravind.learning.hadoop.mapred.techtalks.StackoverflowDataWranglerDriver data/stackoverflow-posts.xml data/so-posts-tsv
```