# Parsing xml files on hadoop...

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, xml-parsing, mapreduce

How does one parse an xml file on Hadoop with structure like following:

```
<row Id="2292" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="2284" CreationDate="2008-08-05T13:28:06.700" Score="0" ViewCount="0" Body="&lt;p&gt;The first thing you should do is contact the main people who run the open source project. Ask them if it is ok to contribute to the code and go from there.&lt;/p&gt;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Simply writing your improved code and then giving it to them may result in your code being rejected.&lt;/p&gt;" OwnerUserId="383" LastActivityDate="2008-08-05T13:28:06.700" />
```

Note: I have written code for it but its not workin correctly. Need a fresh approach...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @TechCrunch yes, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445528/parsing-of-stackoverflows-posts-xml-on-hadoop/19591736#19591736)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [XMLInputFormat](http://xmlandhadoop.blogspot.co.uk/), it may have to modified a bit.

Comment: for the start tag & end tag i used "<row" &"/>" but could not get correct o/p... could u pls suggest any change..

Comment: @AnilKrShokeen : try using `<row>` and `</row>` as start and end tags respectivly.